# How to make text center inside stack

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to make my text centered inside of a Stack widget. This is what I have attempted so far. Right now, it's to the left on top of the image and that's not where I want it to be. I've tried using the `Align` widget and the `Center` widget but to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

```
Flexible(
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8,top: 8,bottom: 8,right: 8),
    child: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Wrap(
          children: <Widget>[ 
            Image.network("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcR1OlcL_Laxy1rcct4vok3rkEb3l6NdV1pncE1_K1mzZ9NDYy3J",
               height: 100,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2,
          height: 100,
          child: Center(
            child: Wrap(
              children: <Widget>[
                Center(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 100,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2,
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Text(
                        "BOOKS AND BOOKLETS",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white, 
                          fontSize: 18,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

[image]

Any option to make this text in center

```
 Expanded(child: Card(
              child: Container(
                child: Center(
                  child:  Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Image.network("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcR1OlcL_Laxy1rcct4vok3rkEb3l6NdV1pncE1_K1mzZ9NDYy3J",
                        height: 100,
                      ),
                      SafeArea(child: Text("asdad"))
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ))
```

Problem identifed if text size is small (means "abc") it is working but if text size is large(measn "abc abc abc acb acb abc") it is not workging
How to solve this issue?

Comment: Can we see the whole code, aka above the Flexible widget?

Comment: Also, you can use `EdgeInsets.all(8)` instead of specifying all of them individually.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:

```
Container(
        width: 500,
        height: 100,
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.network(
              "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcR1OlcL_Laxy1rcct4vok3rkEb3l6NdV1pncE1_K1mzZ9NDYy3J",
              height: 100,
              width: 500,
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text(
                "BOOKS AND BOOKLETS",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 11,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
```

Comment: Problem identifed if text size is small (means "abc") it is working but if text size is large(measn "abc abc abc acb acb abc") it is not workging
How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I want at it by a different approach, what if you used a `Container` widget and decorate it using a background image? Then, you can avoid using a `Stack` widget altogether.

Here's the minimal code:

```
return Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
  child: Container(
    height: 500,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: NetworkImage(
          "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcR1OlcL_Laxy1rcct4vok3rkEb3l6NdV1pncE1_K1mzZ9NDYy3J",
        ),
      ),
    ),
    child: Center(
      child: Text(
        "hi",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 56),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Problem identifed if text size is small (means "abc") it is working but if text size is large(measn "abc abc abc acb acb abc") it is not workging
How to solve this issue?

Comment: I have remade my answer @Midhilaj.

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```
 Expanded(
          child: Card(
            child: Container(

              child: Center(
                child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Image.network("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcR1OlcL_Laxy1rcct4vok3rkEb3l6NdV1pncE1_K1mzZ9NDYy3J",
                      height: 100,
                    ),
                    Positioned.fill(
                      child:Center(child:Align(
                        child:  Text("BOOKS AND BOOKLETS",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 18,color: Colors.white),textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                      )
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `textAlign: TextAlign.center` inside your `Text Widget`

using `alignment: Alignment.center` inside your `Container Widget` could also help

No need to use so many widgets just put `Text` widget inside `Container` Widget
and use alignment property of both widgets

that should resolve the issue.

```
     Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2,
          height: 100,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
             child: Text(
                     "BOOKS AND BOOKLETS",
                     textAlign: TextAlign.center
                     style: TextStyle(
                       color: Colors.white, 
                       fontSize: 18,
                       fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                       ),
                     ),
                   )
```